# Google Play Games Stops Working Properly after adding Firebase Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Before adding firebase plugin i used to get the email selection dialog for google play games authenticate and on success i could get the email by using 
string email = ((PlayGamesLocalUser) Social.localUser).Email;

But after i have added firebase the dialog doesn't come although it goes in success block after authentication i can only get user id .
Using Play Games Plugin 0.9.3.7.
I need to get user email and make the dialog to show also as before.
Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused because of some issue with conflicting plugins. You should try to resolve this by using Play Services Resolver for Unity - it is available under the Assets menu.

Comment: Thanks for replying... But when i added firebase it itself solved the dependencies as the resolving dependencies dialog came up for quite a while ..

Comment: Just to reconfirm i did that again and it said resolution succeeded

Comment: Any other help ?